# Python Pandas round is not working correctl

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, rounding

I tried to round up my dataframe's revenue column for 2 decimals.
Yet, for several rows, it is not working correctly.

```
sample['REVENUE']
12830     0.0000
12831     3.3600
12832     3.1680
12833    13.0061
12834    13.2150
12835    64.5450
12836   113.5350
12837   245.0000
12838    27.7750
Name: REVENUE, dtype: float64

np.round(sample['REVENUE'], decimals = 2)
12830     0.0000
12831     3.3600
12832     3.1700
12833    13.0100
12834    13.2200
12835    64.5400
12836   113.5400
12837   245.0000
12838    27.7800
Name: REVENUE, dtype: float64
```

All lines are rounding fine, but for line 12835, it is rounding down even though it should be rounding up, 64.545 --> 64.55, but result is 64.54.

Can anyone help me about this?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with that. `round` converts halves to the nearest even

Comment: Then, How I can round it like excel? for example, 64.545 should be 64.55, not 64.54.

Comment: @JasonLim in case your question is answered, feel free to accept an answer to "close" the question. *flies away*

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned numpy rounds to the next even value. This is where your "error" comes from. In general this is due to the way floating point numbers are stored.More information can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50374779/how-to-avoid-incorrect-rounding-with-numpy-round).

A fast win would be to go with Python's internal function (more details [here](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_round.asp))

```
print(round(64.5450, 2))
>> 64.55
```

You can also continue and read into [decimal fixed point and floating point arithmetic](https://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html), to take it from here.